# I accidentally deleted pr einstalled software for uninstalling apps and I don't have any backup plz help

Tags: applications

I accidentally deleted pr einstalled software for uninstalling apps and I don't have any backup plz help
Phone-Panasonic p31
Android 4.2.2
I also reset my phone 2-3 times but noting happen

Comment: More info needed. You can always do a factory reset for restoring the phone.

Answer (score 0):

If factory reset doesn't work then you can download the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to your PC or Mac and reading up on the documentation to see how to restore the components that are missing or how to re-install the whole system.  Be sure and look at how to back everything up before the restore and again afterwards.